# Frequent BLE disconnection - Android marshmallow+

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**The Problem:**
The bluetooth connection between the android app(GATT client) and two TI  boards(CC2640R2F, GATT server) is unstable. When the android app connects to the two boards, the bluetooth connection state of the two boards toggle rapidly between connected and disconnected states. As a result the service discovery process is affected and sometimes there are no GATT characteristics discovered(The GATT service is just empty). The problem occurs with only android devices running marshmallow(6.0+) and above. 
This issue also occurs on other third-party apps available in the play store such as BLE scanner, sensorTag and nrf connect running on those android devices.

**Fixes attempted  on Android side:**
The following fixes were attempted on the Android side but these were unsuccessful.
a time delay(tried upto 2000ms) was set between connection successful event and gatt.discoverServices() request.
Have separate device.gattConnect(...) methods for devices below and above marshmallow(6.0). Devices above marshmallow require a TRANSPORT parameter. 
Switch connection between the GATT servers to ensure that only one server is connected at a given time. 
Created separate Gatt callbacks for the two servers and separate threads for all the operations that took place involving the two servers.
The only fix that was successful is connecting only one server to the client. To connect another server, the app needs to be reopened. If another device is connected at the same time, the issue still occurs.

**Data Collected:**
The bluetooth sniffer logs were collected from the android side and are attached.
The ['btsnoop_hci_success.log'](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0mbRXH8AXhNVGJuSTVTVXNaUjQ) file deals with the successful BLE connection between an android device(Samsung galaxy s7 edge) running marshmallow(6.0.1) and just one server(a purifier).
The ['btsnoop_hci_fail.log'](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0mbRXH8AXhNbWRzeHZBSUhHSlk) file deals with the problematic BLE connection between the same android device and two servers(a sensor and a purifier).